# How to avoid `operator[](const char*)` ambiguity?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
class DictionaryRef {
public:    
  operator bool() const;
  std::string const& operator[](char const* name) const;

  // other stuff
};

int main() {
  DictionaryRef dict;
  char text[256] = "Hello World!";

  std::cout << dict[text] << std::endl;
}
```

This produces the following warning when compiled with G++:

```
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
note: candidate 1: const string& DictionaryRef::operator[](const char*) const
note: candidate 2: operator[](long int, char*) <built-in>
```

I know what this means (and the cause is been explained in [operator[](const char *) ambiguity](/q/25113661/4850040)) but I'm looking for a way to ensure correct behavior/resolve the warning without changing my class design - since it makes perfect sense for a class to have both a boolean conversion, and a `[](const char*)` operator.

What's the purpose of `operator[](long int, char*)` besides generating random compiler warnings? I can't imagine someone writing `1["hello"]` in real code.

Comment: My guess would be that it's c legacy. In c, `array[index]` is just another notation for `*(array + index)`, so swapping `array` and `index` has no influence on the result (of course, even in c code that use is very rare).

Comment: `explicit operator bool() const` seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Make the conversion to bool explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Although you "can't imagine someone writing `1["hello"]` in a real code", this is something that's legal C++, as a consequence of the commutative `[]` inherited from C.  Reasonable or not, that's how the language is defined, and it's unlikely to be changing for us.

The best way to avoid the ambiguity is to add `explicit` to the boolean conversion - it's very rare that we ever want a non-explicit `operator bool()`.

An alternative is to replace `operator bool()` with an `operator void*()`, which will still satisfy boolean tests, but not convert to integer.